# Loading the NOOBS image for 1st time -- What's the purpose of the "Data Partition" selection

Tags: boot, software-installation, noobs, partition

I hate to sound stupid but I just wanted to know, when I copy and paste the NOOBS package onto a fresh microsd and load it into my pi, on first startup I get these options:

- Raspbian
- Data Partition
- Raspian - Boot to Scratch

I understand option #1 & option #3, but why would you select this option? I guess I'm asking for examples

Answer (score 6):

As explained [here](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/operating-system-s/item/143-noobs-new-out-of-the-box-software), the "Data Partition" option creates a buffer that is untouched when the OS is installed. Like any partition, it segregates memory so that if a OS is reinstalled to the SD card, it doesn't wipe out all the preexisting memory.

> Data Partition - Add a 512mb data partition for data that will be kept safe during a re-instalation of an operating system.

A [source here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Adding_a_data_partition_.28Optional.29) goes into further detail on what it does.

It sounds to me like selecting that option will allow you to create a 'recovery disk' of sorts. It might have come as a result of [discussion on this issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/196), where people requested a partition that persists despite wiping another partition on the Pi.

I hope this helps!